# How to inject elements into character content with Closure XML?

Tags: xml, lisp, common-lisp, sax

I need to transform all characters | to tags  in all texts blocks of a big XML file. That is, whenever I found

```xml
<test att="one|two">content | something more | and done</test>
```

I need to transform to

```xml
<test att="one|two">content <bar/> something more <bar/> and done</test>
```

Note that | can also occur in attributes values and, in that case, they must be keeped unchanged. After reading the [Transforming](http://common-lisp.net/project/cxml/saxoverview/pages/11.html) slide of the SAX Overview part of the CXML focumentation, I wrote

```lisp
(defclass preproc (cxml:sax-proxy) ())

(defmethod sax:characters ((handler preproc) data)
  (call-next-method handler (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "\\|" data "<bar/>")))
```

But of course, it produces a string (escaped) not a tag in the final XML.

```lisp
WML> (cxml:parse "<test>content | ola</test>"
                     (make-instance 'preproc
                                    :chained-handler (cxml:make-string-sink)))
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>content &lt;bar/&gt; ola</test>"
```

Any idea or directions?

Comment: This question isn't about the "commerce eXtensible Markup Language", so I removed the [tag:cxml] tag.

Comment: cxml is the name of the CL package not  "commerce eXtensible Markup Language".

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the package; it's a dependency of my [CL-RDFXML](https://github.com/tayloj/cl-rdfxml) parser.  However, the [tag:cxml] tag on Stack Overflow, according to its tag wiki, is for the "commerce eXtensible Markup Language".  If you hover the mouse cursor over the tag, it shows the description.  (Incidentally, I see this happen a lot with the [tag:owl] and [tag:owl-carousel] tags.)

Comment: But aside from that, did the answer help, or did it not translate well to the actual problem domain?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor clear now to me why is not adequate to use the tag cxml, thanks. BTW, CL-RDFXML is great, thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

The handler doesn't call the parser, but is *handling* already parsed values.  So, rather than constructing a *string* that contains **<bar/>**, what you want to do is to call the method that would have been called if **<bar/>** had actually been encountered.  In this case, if the document had actually had

```xml
content <bar/> ola
```

inside the **test** element, then there would have been the calls:

```lisp
(sax:characters handler "content ")
(sax:start-element handler nil nil "bar" '())
(sax:end-element handler nil nil "bar"
(sax:characters handler " ola")
```

So, all you need to do is split the string on the **|** character (you can use CL-PPCRE for this if you want, though there may be more lightweight solutions), and then do a **call-next-method** for each string part, and do calls to **sax:start-element** and **sax:end-element** in between:

```lisp
(defmethod sax:characters ((handler preproc) data)
  (let ((parts (cl-ppcre:split "\\|" data)))
    ;; check this on edge cases, though, e.g., "", "|", "a|", strings
    ;; without any "|", etc.
    (call-next-method handler (pop parts))
    (dolist (part parts)
      (sax:start-element handler nil nil "bar" '())
      (sax:end-element handler nil nil "bar")
      (call-next-method handler part))))
```

```
(cxml:parse "<test>content | ola</test>"
            (make-instance 'preproc
                           :chained-handler (cxml:make-string-sink)))
;=> 
; "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
; <test>content <bar/> ola</test>"
```

Comment: This answer is almost identifical of the one that I received from Russ Tyndall in the Cxml-devel list yesterday (http://mailman.common-lisp.net/pipermail/cxml-devel/2014-November/000009.html)!

Comment: about "The handler doesn't call the parser, but is handling already parsed values...". I don't understand this comment. Sure the handler doesn't call the parser, I've never suspect the opposite. What is new for me here is that we can call sax:start-element or sax:end-element methods (that is, fire events) and not only respond to them.

Comment: sure, it is a good sign! ;-) BTW, can you help me with the follow up questions that I posted in the list? http://mailman.common-lisp.net/pipermail/cxml-devel/2014-November/subject.html

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker If you post it as a separate Stack Overflow question, I (along with lots of others) will probably get to take  a look.  It did look like a separate issue from this one.

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker What I meant by that comment is the that SAX separates the parsing (reading the document) from the handling.  The parser is responsible for calling methods on the handler that correspond to what was in the document.  The way to simulate something else being in the document is not (as you noted) by injecting it into the character content (since that won't be parsed), but by calling the methods that would have been called if it was there. Note that the SAX handlers don't have be used in conjunction with a parser; you can use them to *generate* XML documents. In that light...

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker ...what you're doing is really using a parser to generate a stream of events, and then using a handler to serialize a new document based on a modified version of that stream.